# Wrong thumbnails in CKFinder

Tags: php, ckeditor, ckfinder

I am using CKFinder and configured it to replace image files if uploaded again with same name instead of duplicating the file by extending numbers at the end of the file name. But the problem here is the image is getting overwrite but the thumbnail showing is old.

```
$config['overwriteOnUpload'] = true;
```

I've set `overwriteOnUpload=true` in config file. What's the problem with the thumbnail.

CKFinder Version - 3.1

Comment: Could you write which version of CKFinder are you using?

Comment: updated question @jodator

Comment: AFAIR this might have been fixed in recent releases. Current version is `v3.4.5` so you're using very old one.

Comment: Ok will check with the new version. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, It's have been fixed in the latest version. But we are using 3.1 and its paid, we don't want to upgrade the version only wanted to fix this. Is there any way without upgrading the version

Comment: From what I know, no back-fixes are being provided for CKFinder so the only solution seems to be upgrading. Since you have a license, I think you should rather contact CKFinder support and ask your question there as they may have a different solution for you. It's worth trying if you ask me.

Comment: ok Thanks, will try.